# Lorentz Force Formula Question

Tags: electromagnetism

I recently got into researching about the lorentz force and I found 2 formulas for the amount of force and I'm confused about the difference between the two. The formulas are:

$$F = q(\vec{E} + \vec{v} \times \vec{B})\tag{1}$$
$$F = I L B \tag{2}$$

What is the difference between the usages of these two?

Comment: Where did you find them?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) explains both equations.

Answer (score 2):

$$\vec{F}=q(\vec{E}+\vec{v}\times\vec{B}) \tag{1}$$
is the [Lorentz force](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magfie.html#c2) experienced by a single point charge $q$
when moving with velocity $\vec{v}$ through space.
As you can see, it is the sum of two parts:
the electric force $q\vec{E}$,
and the magnetic force $q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$.

$$\vec{F}=\vec{I}L\times\vec{B} \tag{2}$$
is the [magnetic force](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magfor.html#c1) experienced by a piece of wire
(with length $L$, and an electric current $I$ flowing through it).

Actually both equations are related.
Equation (2) can be derived from equation (1),
because the current $I$ is made up by many charges $q$,
each moving with a velocity $\vec{v}$.

Answer (score 0):

(Notation- Bolface characters represent vector quantities and italicized characters represent scalars. |**V**| represents the magnitude of the vector **V**. The symbol × represents the vector cross product).

Equation (1) is the equation of the Lorentz Force on a charged particle in an electromagnetic field, it describes the net external force acting on a charged particle of charge *q* moving with a velocity  **v** in the presence of an electric field **E** and a magnetic field **B**.

Equation (2) is an application of (1) upon the charges moving in a finite straight wire carrying a current *i*, to yield the net force acting on a conducting wire due to an external uniform magnetic field **B**.
Consider a wire carrying a current *i* in a uniform magnetic field **B**. The electrons (carrying charge *-e*) flowing through the wire can be assumed to be moving with a drift speed *v* opposite to the direction of the current. The net force **F** acting on any such mobile electron can be written as:
**F** = *-e***v**×**B**

Since **v** is opposite to the direction of the current, we can write
**v** = -*v*(**dl**/*dl*), **dl** being along the direction of the current in the part of the wire where this electron is situated.
Thus, we can write
|**F**| = |*-e***v**×**B**| = |*e* *v*(**dl**)×**B**/*dl*| =    *e* *v*|**B**|*sin(θ)*, *θ* being the angle between **B** and **dl**.

Note that the other charged particles in the wire are not mobile due to their massive nature and thus do not experience any force due to the magnetic field. Thus, the net force on the wire is given by summing **F** over all the electrons in the wire.

The unit vector **M** along this force is given by the unit vector along the direction of the cross product **dl**×**B**.

In the case of a finite straight wire, **dl** and *θ* are the same for each electron in the wire. Thus, all the forces act in the same direction, allowing the forces to be added algebraically as follows-

∑|**F**| = ∑*e* *v*|**B**|*sin(θ)* = *e* *v*|**B**| ∑*sin(θ)* = *N* *e* *v*|**B**| *sin(θ)*

Where *N* is the number of electrons in the wire. Considering the number of electrons per unit volume to be *n* and the length and cross sectional area of the wire to be *L* and *A* respectively, we know that the current through the wire is given by:

*i* = *n* *e* *A* *v* = *N* *e* *A* *v*/*A* *L* = *N* *e* *v*/*L*.

Thus, the net force can be rewritten as:
∑|**F**| = *N* *e* *v*|**B**| *sin(θ)* = *L* (*N* *e* *v*/*L*)|**B**| *sin(θ)* = *L* *i* |**B**| *sin(θ)*

Let **L** represent a vector of magnitude *L* in the direction of the current. Reincorporating vector notations, the net force vector on the wire can now be written as follows:

*L* *i* |*B*| *sin(θ)* **M** = *i* (*L* |*B*| *sin(θ)* **M**) = *i* (**L**×**B**)

Cheers!